# Display Tumblr post content differently using tags

Tags: tumblr

I don't know if what I want it's possible or not, but what I'm looking for is a way of displaying content differently, using tags.

If I have a post with a tag `#movies`, I would want to display an image of a camera. If the tag is `#music`, I would like to display an image of a radio.

Comment: It could be done, have you tried anything at all. It is customary on SO to post what you have tried/your code, other people will be less likely to write code for you.

Comment: What @lharby said. I would suggest taking a look at the Tumblr HTML docs: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: Well the reason I didn't share any code was only because the things I've tried were already on the page @mikedidthis shared. I've tried to use the tags as classes, but that wouldn't work because I needed something to identify the tag and to show something specific for that tag, not for every tag.

Comment: Well the reason I didn't share any code was only because the things I've tried were already on the page @mikedidthis shared. I've tried to use the tags as classes, but that wouldn't work because I needed something to identify the tag and to show something specific for that tag, not for every tag. But thank you for the responses :) next time I will share something that may help a little more on what my problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this immediately under `{block:Posts}`, or before `{/block:Posts}` depending on where you want the signifier to be.

```
{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags}
<script type='text/javascript'>
var {Tag} = '{Tag}'; if ({Tag} == 'movies')
{document.write('Movies blah blah');}
</script>
{/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
```

This should display the text "Movies blah blah" wherever you put the code on posts you tag with the tag "movies" (case sensitive).

Simply repeat for other tags.